# neovim on windows with FZF

Tags: vim, neovim, fzf, scoop-installer, vim-fzf

I am using neovim-qt on windows. I have install fzf with help of Scoop package manager on windows.

All the required plugins for neovim are installed using vim-plug and list under a file called _plugrc. (Other plugged plug-ins are working without any issue. _plugrc is included in init.vim)

I configured FZF recently. The FZF installation is done using following lines

```
" FZF
Plug 'C:/Apps/Packages/Scoop/apps/fzf/current'
Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim'
```

My intention is to use fzf binary on windows along with fzf.vim. Neovimo issues and error whenever I invoke **'Files'** command in neovim.

Error:

```
Error detected while processing function fzf#vim#files[15]..<SNR>91_fzf[18]..<SNR<91_wrap:
line 12:
E117: Unknown function fzf#wrap
E15: Invalid expression: fzf#2wrap(a:name, opts, a:bang)
line 14:
E121: Undefined variable: wrapped
E15: Invalid expression: wrapped
Error detected while processing function fzf#vim#files[15]..<SNR>91_fzf:
line 18:
E117: Unknow fucntion: fzf#run
E15: Invalid expression: fzf#run(s:wrap(a:name, merged. bang))
```

I think it is unable to use the scoop install FZF. Help me to configure it.

Comment: Under `C:/Apps/Packages/Scoop/apps/fzf/current`, do you have a file `plugin/fzf.vim` present? That's where `fzf#wrap` is supposed to be defined... Perhaps your Scoop install is installing the `fzf` binary but not the required files for Vim...

Comment: Under the current directory, it is just the binary which is fzf.exe. fzf.vim is plugged separately.

Comment: If you look at https://github.com/junegunn/fzf?files=1 you'll see that it has both the sources *and* a `plugin/fzf.vim` that's what Vim needs...

Comment: let me give this a try

Answer (score 3):

Following @filbranden advice, this it what is required:

1. Goto `C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\scoop\apps\fzf\XXXXX`
2. Create the dir `plugin`
3. Place within it `fzf.vim` from https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/master/plugin/fzf.vim

**BUT!!!** It's much easier to rather just add:
`Plug 'junegunn/fzf'` to your init.vim to plug the above file (i.e. in addition to `Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim'`)